# File is both modified and untracked

Tags: git

## Why I'm asking the question

The following `git status` output shows a file that is both deleted and untracked:

```
$ git status
On branch bugfix/1386ReferredBySlow
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
modified:   Broker/Controllers/InHouseAgentsController.cs
modified:   Broker/Web.config
deleted:    CompanyNameEnterprise.EF/App.Config
modified:   CompanyNameEnterprise.Services/Web.config
Untracked files:
 (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
CompanyNameEnterprise.EF/App.config
```

The file `CompanyNameEnterprise.EF/App.config` is both "deleted" and "untracked."  Those two states seem contradictory.

## The Question

Under what circumstances can git show that a file is both untracked and deleted?

## More info

- Windows 10
- Bash
- git version 2.13.0
- VisualStudio/C# project

## How we worked around it.

My co-worker worked around it by re-cloning the project, which fixed the problem (and destroyed the evidence).  But I want to know why this can happen so we know what to do next time.

Comment: Status shows the file as deleted and untracked. Is it possible the file was deleted and then re-created?

Comment: @daan.desmedt Thank you for the edit.  I never remember which markdown engines do triple-tricks and which don't.

Comment: I incorrectly stated that the file was both "modified" and "untracked"; the `git status` actually shows that it was both "deleted" and "untracked."  I've corrected the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

seems like the problem is related to ignoring the case of the file name: the untracked one has a lowercase 'c' while the deleted one a uppercase 'C'. Maybe the file was renamed?!

I assume the `core.ignorecase` configuration variable can help: [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-coreignoreCase) (or not if not set correctly).

> If true, this option enables various workarounds to enable Git to work better on filesystems that are not case sensitive, like FAT. ...

Use `git config --get --show-origin core.ignorecase` to check its value and origin.

Comment: Indeed.  OP - have you turned off `core.ignorecase`?

Comment: My co-worker has not changed `core.ignorecase` from its default (which I assume is false).  This seems like the most likely cause of the issue.

Comment: by documentation `git clone` and `git init` can set it to `true` "if appropriate"... you can check it with `git config --get core.ignorecase`

Answer (score 2):

It happens when you remove a file, add the deletion to stage and recreate this file. File will appear in staged and untracked sections.

You can see details with `git diff` and `git diff --staged`

Steps to reproduce :

1. Remove a file with `git rm file`
2. Recreate this file with a non-git tool
3. You can see your file in staged and untracked sections. Use `git diff --staged` to see changes before addition, and `git diff` to see changes after addition

[image: Screenshot after remove and restore]

A similar thing will appear when you edit a file, add changes to stage and modify the file again. Your file will be appear in staged and unstaged sections. (i.e after a partial addition with `git add -p`)

[image: Screenshot after double edition]

Comment: I can make a file show up as both staged and modified this way, but I cannot figure out how to make it show up as both untracked and modified.

Comment: Try to execute `git rm file.txt; touch file.txt; git status`. Your file is marked as deleted and untracked. If you restore file with `git checkout -- file.txt`, git will mark your file as modified, you must use `touch` to reproduce

Comment: I think you're confusing "untracked files" (files absent from the index) with "unstaged changes" (files which exist with different content on-disk and in the index).

Comment: When editing a file twice, changes will be displayed in staged and unstaged sections. When delete and recreate, file will be appear in staged and untracked.

Comment: This does indeed recreate the problem.  I confused myself by stating, incorrectly, that the file was both "modified" and "untracked."  @sboye and others correctly figured out that it was actually both "deleted" and "untracked."

Answer (score 2):

`CompanyNameEnterprise.EF/App.config` is not `modified`, it is `deleted`. In other words, it is present in the last commit but not in the index (aka "staging area").

It is indeed untracked, i.e. present on-disk but not in the index.

To sum up, it is present in the last commit and on disk, but absent from the index. This happens right after your run `git rm --cached` on the file for example.

Comment: You are correct--I had goofed up the problem description.  Thank you for pointing it out, and for suggesting a possible cause.